# DDD - Finding the right boundaries for an aggegrate with a three-level structure

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am currently developing an app based on an API and I could use some help on how to define the appropriate boundary for an aggegrate.

My app is very simple and has three levels that build on each other. Each level, except the last, can contain multiple 1:N instances of the next level. A lower level cannot exist without the higher level.

If I now delete level 1, for example, then all subordinate levels are also deleted. For me, this would be an indication of an aggegrate. However, level 1 can theoretically contain 100 level 2 instances. That would be pretty huge for an aggregate...

Since the cohesiveness of the levels is very strong and a lower level may not be linked directly to another lower level, it already feels like a bound context.

How would you solve this?
Thanks :)

[image: Concept]

Comment: I think I would first go for one aggregate. It's the simplest solution and encapsulation is guaranteed. Of course, if you hit performance issues (which is likely) you can start breaking up into smaller aggregates on the appropriate level. Operations such as creation/deletion/updating would then need to communicate (by events/messages) to lower level aggregates.

Comment: Thanks. That's right. I think I will treat level 2 and 3 as one aggegrate. Since there are few instances on level 1 and the third level is the most extensive.